# How to test with PowerMock a method which calls another private void method from the same class?

Tags: java, testing, junit, powermock

I have a class which have some methods like in the example.

```
public class TestClass {

    public boolean aMethod()
    {
        voidMethod();
        return true;
    }

    private void voidMethod()
    {
        ... does something ...
    }

    ... other methods ...
}
```

I want to test `aMethod` with powermock and all methods should work normally except the `voidMethod`.
I've created a partial mock of `TestClass` to make `voidMethod` do nothing.But I don't know how to expect call of this method.

```
testObject = createPartialMock(TestClass.class, "voidMethod");
expectPrivate(testObject, "voidMethod");
```

I'm getting an error on second line:

> The method expect(T) in the type EasyMock is not applicable for the arguments (void)

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 2):

Use simple call like this:

```
testObject.voidMethod(); // don't use "expect" for voids
expectLastCall().times(3); // use this for expectations
```

And don't forget `reply()` after all you expectations and `verify()` after running tested code.

Comment: sorry I had a mistake but it doesn't change behavior.voidMethod is called from aMethod and it's a private method.Anyway I expect call of voidMethod from aMethod.If even voidMethod would public, whether testObject.voidMethod(); relates to my testing aMethod??

Comment: Since voidMethod() is private, this answer can never work, it won't even compile.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like PowerMock can't mock a private void method (only private methods with a value returned).  They should really provide a more useful compiler error to explicitly say that.  EasyMock doesn't mock private methods at all.  @StanislawLeventhal's answer references the syntax for expecting (recording) calls to a non-private void method using EasyMock.

What you should do first is consider whether what you are trying to do makes sense, and what really needs to be mocked.  Consider it a code smell when you are mocking a private method; maybe you need to do it, but usually, there is a way to avoid it.  It sounds obvious to think critically about why you are mocking, but it's easy to get confused and miss things.

Why should you have a private method in your test class that you can't directly call and need to mock instead, but which doesn't return a value?  Mocking is normally used to control what is returned from a method; here, you are basically saying that this method must be called, but you want to override its implementation with nothing (if I understand correctly).  I'm not sure I can think of a situation where this would be useful or necessary in a test class.  The example you provided is too generalized to understand the reasoning behind, but you should try to see if there is a better way to achieve your goal.

Comment: If this answered the question, would you mind marking it as the answer?

Comment: I initially upvoted this answer, but a day later I revisited the problem and I can't reproduce it. What shift66 asked seems to work for me without the exception.